# Randomizing and shuffling questions

Tags: python

I am very new in python
and now I'm having a trouble with this program

```
from random import shuffle
question = [["What's the color of the sky when night?", "black"],
            ["How many numbers in this given: ak2ks1l2", "3"],
            ["Who's the man's best friend?", "dog"]]
shuffle(question)

for i in range(3):
    answer = question[i][1]
    question = question[i][0]
    given_answer = input(question)
    if answer == given_answer:
        print("Correct")    
    else:
        print("Incorrect, correct was:", answer)
```

it errors after answering the first question. Any solution or help? Thanks!

Comment: you need to improve your variable naming..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overwriting `question` variable in a `for` loop:

```
question = question[i][0]
```

Use another variable name.

```
from random import shuffle
questions = [["What's the color of the sky when night?", "black"],
            ["How many numbers in this given: ak2ks1l2", "3"],
            ["Who's the man's best friend?", "dog"]]
shuffle(questions)

for question, answer in questions: # easier to read than: for i in range(3):..[i]
    given_answer = input(question)
    if answer == given_answer:
        print("Correct")    
    else:
        print("Incorrect, correct was:", answer)
```